# Why are some contrib module functions not recognized?

Tags: 7, installation, social-network

I can't seem to get the latest twitter module to work with my site.

I have a custom module that does some sanity checks on user-imported twitter accounts and my site keeps failing at this point. After some digging I noticed the twitter module functino `twitter_account_load()` is not recognized at all.

Devel test code to reproduce:

```
dpm(module_load_all()); // returns 1
dpm(module_exists('twitter')); // returns 1
dpm(twitter_account_load('@twitter')); // returns white screen of death
```

Apache error log:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function twitter_account_load() in /var/www/mysite/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/contrib/devel/devel.module(1285) : eval()'d code on line 4, referer: http://my.site.com/devel/php

Drupal Version 7.26
Twitter Version 7.x-5.8

What I have tried so far:

- Cache cleared
- Twitter module upgrade to latest 5.8
- Cache cleared
- Twitter module reinstall
- Cache cleared
- ...

Nothing worked.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do [module load include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) of twitter.inc in which above function was defined.. .module files are automatically included, but .inc are not. So you need to include them using above function...

```
module_load_include('inc', 'twitter', 'twitter');
dpm(module_load_all()); // returns 1
dpm(module_exists('twitter')); // returns 1
dpm(twitter_account_load('@twitter'));
```

Comment: @vertoe .module files are automatically included, but .inc not. So, if you need a function that is in a .inc file usually you have to include manually.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that. Your code works. Million thansk!